# How to adjust Key Derivation Iterations on iOS Key generation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, security, cryptography

I'm currently working on an app that needs to communicate with a secure system. I need to generate a public and private key according to a couple of requirements. According to system specs, the key derivation iterations is required to be set to 1000, but I can't find any way to do this on iOS.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Your question is too broad.  You are not clear as to which part you have difficulty with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comment, your question is a bit too broad. I am guessing that you are asking about [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2).

You can use CommonCrypto to do that. I used it with Objective-C and it was relatively easy. I think there might be some difficulties to use it with Swift, but Google search has a lot of info how to do that.

You will need to use CommonCrypto function `CCKeyDerivationPBKDF` - [link to docs](https://opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-55010/CommonCrypto/CommonKeyDerivation.h). There is a `round` parameter which I think is what you are looking for.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691613/swift-how-to-call-cckeyderivationpbkdf-from-swift) might help too.

Comment: Will try out your answer. Thanks for answering, even though the question was a bit too broad. Will accept it once I've verified that this is what is required.

Comment: @user1945317 you might want to check also `CCCalibratePBKDF` which can tell you how many rounds you need to set to achieve a desired slowdown in seconds as it also depends on device hardware (different for iPhone5 and iPhone7). I am not sure if your only requirement is a number of rounds but usually a processing time is a requirement and not rounds.

Comment: Thanks! This is enough to continue working again. I'm using the joeymeyer/PBKDF2-Wrapper project on GitHub to make it a bit easier to work with.